# JQuery .on() binding does not work after part of page is reloaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, binding

On my page I have a filter form for a report. The form is submitted via ajax and then I reload part of the page. After the part of the page is reladed, jQuery bindings no longer work in the reladed parts of the page.

Here is my html:

```
<input type="button" id="mainButton" value="Reload the container"/>
<div id="reloadable" style="border: 1px solid black;">
    <input type="button" class="supplimentalButton" value="You should see alert" />
</div>
```

This is jQuery 1.9.1 bindings:

```
// this bit works just fine first time.
// but after reload the binding is no longer attached 
// and alert is not coming up on button click
$('.supplimentalButton').on('click',function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});

// this is what reloads the container
$('#mainButton').on('click', function(){
    $('#reloadable').html('<input type="button" class="supplimentalButton" value="Alert does not work anymore" />');
});
```

And here is the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/trailmax/4JEQv/4/

So far all the advice I've seen was was to use `.on()` binding. And that is what I'm doing. Any advice on the issue?

Comment: Because the elements did not exist when you bound the events! Read the [documentation of `on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/), it explains it.

Comment: @epascarello yes, that's why I use `.on()` - one of the suggested use in the documentation.

Comment: Did you read the section ["Direct and delegated events"](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) in the docs? Explains it all with an example.

Comment: I did skim through.. should've paid more attention there -)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#reloadable').on('click','.supplimentalButton',function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});

$('#mainButton').on('click', function(){
    $('#reloadable').html('<input type="button" class="supplimentalButton" value="Alert does not work anymore" />')
});
```

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/4JEQv/5/

Comment: that worked! thanks. So simple, can't believe I have not tried that after going through the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Use event delegation like

```
$('#reloadable').on('click','.supplimentalButton',function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: that worked! thanks. So simple! can't believe I have not tried that after going through the documentation.